# Change visibility of a control in JSP based on bool value

Tags: javascript, jsp, visibility

I'm guessing I will need to use javascript to do this, but I'm completely clueless. I've never used javascript before. Can someone give me a quick sample of how to change the visibility of a button based on a bool value in a JSP page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking about using it only once it's easy to include JSP value in your JS code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
           var e = document.getElementById("foo");
            var myvar='<%=myScriptletVar %>'
            if (myvar)
                e.style.display = 'none'; 
    </script>
```

Comment: This should work, trying out now. I won't use the scriptlet, I've already got a viewmodel wired up and using expression language instead.

Comment: I included the code I used in another response, because code doesn't format correctly in comments.

But this works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here was my final solution:

```
<c:if test="${viewModel.facebookToken != ''}">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById("facebookButton");
    e.style.display = 'none';
  </script>
</c:if>
```